# Problem to execute SSIS package from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

When i try to execute a package that contains a Dervide Column transformation, i am receiving the following error:

> Package Execution results: {0} Pour exécuter un package SSIS en dehors de SQL Server Data Tools, vous devez installer Integration Services version Colonne dérivée ou ultérieure.

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 then I have installed SSDT 2015 that contain the integration Services but when I execute the application to execute the SSIS Packge this error appear and the package not executed ,in contrast when I put just a source and destination in the package it works .How can I verify that the Integration Services is activated.

Comment: Hi, please explain your problem, do not just post stack error ... But from your error, did you installed "Integration Services version Colonne dérivée" ?

Comment: yes I have installed Visual Studio 2015 then I have installed SSDT 2015 that contain the integration Services but when I execute the application to execute the SSIS Packge this error appear and the package not executed ,in contrast when I put just a source and destination in the package it works .How can I verify that the Integration Services is activated.

Answer (score 0):

From the error above, the derived column transformation is not installed.

Make sure that the `TargetServerVersion` is relevant to the SQL Server version installed.

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)